# How to use overloaded ostream operator with array of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++

In the code bellow, instead of using new function "void print()", how can I use the overloaded "<<" operator in order to print the required information?

Or to be exact, where is the mistake here?

Overloaded << operator in one of the inherited classes:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, DigitSecret &s){
        for(int i=0;i<s.n;i++)
            os<<s.digits[i];

        return os<<" Simple entropy: "<<s.simpleEntropy()<<" Total: "<<s.total();
}


void printAll (Secret ** secrets, int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<secret[i] //This is printing an address, however that is not what i want.
        secrets[i]->print(); //I want that to work like this.

    }
}
```

The whole code: https://pastebin.com/MDCsqUxJ
I want line 134 and 143 to work correctly.

EDIT:

Comment: Dereference the pointer?

Comment: And please stop using pointers for "dynamic arrays", use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. And unless you need polymorphism (i.e. inheritance and virtual functions) then don't have pointers to the objects.

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to pointers to begin with?

Comment: Oh I know about std::vector, but I have this as a homework and the code I get is already written, I just have to add some stuff to make it functional.

Comment: I hate the people that give this up as homework.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I figured it out. Basically in this case, I have to use dynamic_cast with new pointer from the derived class, on  each pointer from the array, and check if the pointer is !=NULL, and then use the overloaded operator on the dereferenced  new pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it this way:

```
void printAll (Secret ** secrets, int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        DigitSecret* ds = NULL;
        CharSecret* cs = NULL;
       ds = dynamic_cast<DigitSecret*>(secrets[i]);
       cs = dynamic_cast<CharSecret*>(secrets[i]);  

        if(ds!=NULL)
            cout<<*ds<<endl;
        else
            cout<<*cs<<endl;
       // secrets[i]->print();

    }
}
```

Basically in this case, I have to use dynamic_cast with new pointer from the derived class, on each pointer from the array, and check if the pointer is !=NULL, and then use the overloaded operator on the dereferenced new pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`secret[i]` is of type `Secret*`, you should derefence first and then your overload will get picked:

```
 cout << *secret[i];
```

---

Side note: use `std::vector` instead of raw dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual std::ostringstream get_value() const = 0;
    int get_id() const { return id_; }
protected:
    int id_;
};

class A:public base {
public:
    A(std::string val):val_(val){ id_ = 1; }
 void print() override { std::cout << " I am A" << std::endl;  }
 std::ostringstream get_value() const { std::ostringstream ss; ss << val_; return ss; }
private:
    std::string val_;
};

class B :public base {
public:
    B(int val):val_(val) { id_ = 2; }
    void print() override { std::cout << " I am B" << std::endl; }
    virtual std::ostringstream get_value() const { std::ostringstream ss; ss << val_; return ss; }
private:
    int val_;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const base* p)
{
    std::string str;
    if (p->get_id() == 1) {
        str = ((A*)(p))->get_value().str();
        os << "A " << str << "\n";
    }
    else
        if (p->get_id() == 2) {
            str = ((B*)(p))->get_value().str();
            os << "B " << str << "\n";
        }
    return os;
}

void PrintAll(base** a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        std::cout << a[i];
}

int main()
{
    base* a[2];
    a[0] = new A("Hello");
    a[1] = new B(10);
    PrintAll(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]